# Access rds postgres db(private access only, no public IP) from ec2 instance in public subnet

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect rds postgres instance which is not publicly accessible from ec2 application using spring boot. Both are in same vpc and ec2 in public subnet and rds in private subnet. -> **failure**

I tried to connect the database inside rds using dbeaver using ssh tunneling(from local->ec2->rds) and it is **successful**.

From ec2 instance I also tried to connect to my database in rds using telnet on port 5432-> **successful**

I tried making the rds  publicly accessible and then I am able to connect to it from the application code -> **successful**

**sample application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 9091
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://test-rds.cpo655l07.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/test
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: test
    password: test
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update # You can use "update" or "create-drop" depending on your needs
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
    database: postgresql
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, test-rds.cpo655l07.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar!/:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar!/:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar!/:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar!/:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar!/:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar!/:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar!/:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1157) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar!/:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:911) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar!/:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar!/:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar!/:2.7.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar!/:2.7.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar!/:2.7.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar!/:2.7.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar!/:2.7.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar!/:2.7.14]
        at org.schoolapp.schoolapp.SchoolAppApplication.main(SchoolAppApplication.java:11) ~[classes!/:0.1.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[school-app-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.1.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at 

        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, test-rds.cpo655l07.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:110) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:331) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.<init>(PoolBase.java:114) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:108) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.ExtractionContext.getQueryResults(ExtractionContext.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.29.jar!/:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.29.jar!/:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.29.jar!/:5.3.29]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Error indicates you are just providing the hostname to the database and not a jbdc url like in your example file.

Comment: I am using the same  url string as  mentioned in the sample application.yml file

Comment: Have you added inbound rule for RDS so that your EC2 instance can connect to it?

Comment: yes, I have added port 5432 in my rds.

Comment: Allow EC2 security group (where spring boot application is deployed) in RDS security group (Add inbound rules with port 5432).

Comment: I already did that

Answer (score -1):

First, double check for any typo errors in RDS URL.

Also note the `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, test-rds.cpo655l07.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com`; this is a key part of the error message.

As such, make sure that the version of Hibernate you're using is compatible with the version of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver you've specified. In your provided configuration, you're using Hibernate `5.6.15.Final`. Confirm that this version is compatible with the version of the driver

Comment: I think the problem is not with the versions as I am able to connect to it when I make rds public